# Set yaml.schema "kubernetes" for autocompletion with nvim-lspconfig

Tags: kubernetes, vim, lua, yaml, nvim-lspconfig

i try to get kubernetes auto completion going in nvim. I am using neovim nightly (0.5.) with 'neovim-lspconfig' and 'nvim-lua/completion-nvim'.
I installed the yaml-language-sever and it is working fine (i know it is working because it is showing errors inside yaml files in nvim).

I am fairly new to lua and nvim-lsp, it might just be a syntax error. I try to configure the server with this lua code:

```
local lspconfig = require'lspconfig'
lspconfig.yamlls.setup{
    on_attach = require'completion'.on_attach,
    settings = {
        yaml.schemas = { kubernetes = "globPattern" },
    }
}
```

I tried thousand different ways to write it but i always get Errors like:

> Error loading lua [string ":lua"]:5: '}' expected (to close '{' at
> line 4) near '='

The [documentation](https://github.com/neovim/nvim-lspconfig/blob/master/CONFIG.md) just says to add server configs via the settings key. But i am not quite sure how.

Anybody got this going? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should change it to

```lua
lspconfig.yamlls.setup{
    settings = {
        yaml = {
           schemas = { kubernetes = "globPattern" },
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. At least the Error is gone with your solution. But still no autocompletion in the yaml files. Is this working for you?

Comment: Check if the server is up (:LspInfo), Set the globPattern to something meaningful for you, like *.yaml

Comment: i got the pattern "/*.yaml". LSP is working since it gives me now error messages in yaml files now. Just no autocompletion :/

Comment: nvm. It works after updating all plugins. Thx!